# I am getting the error "Visual Studio cannot start debugging" when I try to debug

Tags: vb.net

I am receiving the error noted below.  I have built/rebuilt the files several times.  I have also renamed the file in the debug\ *.exe   The NetworkAssociation.exe file is in the debug folder.

> Visual Studio cannot start debugging because the debug     target 'c:\NetworkAssociation\NetworkAssociation\Bin\Debug\NetworkAssociation.exe' is missing.  Please build the project and retry, or set the OutputPath and AssemblyName properties appropriately to point at the correct location.

Answer (score 1):

After doing  a build try some things:

a) Hit Ctrl + F5 to see if the application starts without debugging.
b) Put at the address of the explorer c:\NetworkAssociation\NetworkAssociation\Bin\Debug\NetworkAssociation.exe to se if the application starts.

Please, send back the results of the tests to continue helping.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure what the problem is but the way I'd try to find out is:
Try creating a new project of a similar type and save in a similar location and then close down both projects. Then use some diff tool to compare the .sln and .vbproj files to see if there's some setting/path that looks wrong.